# Copy value from auto search box to an selectable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have an auto search box ,i want to select one by one values from that search box copy to one list to view detail of that search values am using jquery for auto search

Comment: Care to show us some code? Please have a read of FAQs http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: so ,finally what is your question and where is your code ??can you please show us few lines ..